# How to edit user-defined command in GDB

Tags: gdb

For example, I create a command named `print_info`

```
(gdb) define print_info
> i r
> end
```

now I want to edit this command to

```
i r $eax
```

I know I can just run `define print_info` and redefine it. But I want to know if I can just edit it base on the existed command. So that when the command is complex, I don't have to do a complete rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if I can just edit it base on the existed command.

No.

> So that when the command is complex, I don't have to do a complete rewrite.

Save the commands into a file, and use `source filename` to re-define your `print_info` command after editing that file.